# How to make Gmail take into account the good old sig separator?

Tags: gmail, email-signature

When I was small, you'd end your mail (usenet post) with your signature, which was separated from the body of the message with the sequence "-- \n".

And as a result, most (useful) mail clients would cut off the signature in response quotes. I found that so useful. My email conversations get so messy because everybody cites my signature on every response.

Comment: I thought GMail did use and respect the sig separator by default? Certainly does on my Apps Gmail account, my sig is preceded by "-- " on it's own line, and other people's sigs that are marked up properly are grayed out. There's even a GMail labs app that talks about letting you remove the "-- "

Comment: I know that gmail also displays the signature in a lighter color, so its odd that it doesn't remove it from replies.

Answer (score 2):

GMail does respect the sig separator when it encounters it. However GMail's own conversion from richtext to plaintext breaks the separator by stripping off the trailing space.